# Jquery AJAX POST is returning ERROR 500 - Google Text to Speech Module

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-text-to-speech

I have a text to speech module made using google's API, However, it used to work fine (converting user-entered text to speech). But since yesterday I come across this error at Jquery Ajax POST showing error 500 in the console.

The Code goes as :
**Index Page code:**

//On click of speak button after adding text in input fields

```
$('#speak').click(function (e) {

        let _speakBtn = $(this);
        // prevent double click
        if (_speakBtn.attr('disabled')){
            return false;
        }
        _speakBtn.attr('disabled','disabled');

        // validate is content not empty
        if ($("#content").val().length < 1 || $.trim($("#content").val()) === ''){
            $("#content").addClass('is-invalid');
            _speakBtn.prop('disabled',false);
            return false;

        }else{
            $("#content").removeClass('is-invalid');
        }

        // validate is language not empty
        if ($("#language").val().length !== 5 || $.trim($("#language").val()) === ''){
            $("#language").addClass('is-invalid');
            _speakBtn.prop('disabled',false);
            return false;

        }else{
            $("#language").removeClass('is-invalid');
        }

        // validate is voice quality not empty
        if (($("#voice_quality").val() !== 'WaveNet' && $("#voice_quality").val() !== 'Standard') || $.trim($("#voice_quality").val()) === ''){
            $("#voice_quality").addClass('is-invalid');
            _speakBtn.prop('disabled',false);
            return false;

        }else{
            $("#voice_quality").removeClass('is-invalid');
        }

        // validate is gender not empty
        if (($("#gender").val() !== 'Female' && $("#gender").val() !== 'Male') || $.trim($("#gender").val()) === ''){
            $("#gender").addClass('is-invalid');
            _speakBtn.prop('disabled',false);
            return false;

        }else{
            $("#gender").removeClass('is-invalid');
        }

        // validate is artist not empty
        if ($("#artist_name").val().length < 2 || $.trim($("#artist_name").val()) === ''){
            $("#artist_name").addClass('is-invalid');
            _speakBtn.prop('disabled',false);
            return false;

        }else{
            $("#artist_name").removeClass('is-invalid');
        }

        $.post('<?= rtrim(TTS_APP_BASE_URL,'/') ?>/ajax.php', $('.ajax_post').serialize(), function (_response) {
            try {
                _response = JSON.parse(_response);
                if (_response.success){
                    //download audio _response.data.link
                    $('#downloadBtn').attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
                    $('#downloadForm').attr('action', _response.data.down_link);

                    //play audio
                    $('#rk_player').prop('hidden', false);
                    $('#rk_player #rk_source').attr('src', _response.data.play_link);
                    $('#rk_player').get(0).load();
                    $('#rk_player').get(0).play();
                }else{
                    alert(_response.message);
                }
            }catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
            _speakBtn.prop('disabled',false);
        });
    });
```

In the above form the error occured at `$.post('<?= rtrim(TTS_APP_BASE_URL,'/') ?>/ajax.php', $('.ajax_post').serialize(), function (_response) {` line as the data is not being posted to ajax.php

**The Ajax.PHP code :**

```
/*
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST'){
    http_response_code(404);
    die();
}
*/
    define('HAS_ACCESS', TRUE);
    
    require_once 'tts_app.php';
```

**tts_app.php code goes as:**

```
//disable direct access to this file
defined('HAS_ACCESS') or die('silence is golden');


require 'partials/bootstrap.php';

use Classes\HandleResponseClass;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioConfig;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\AudioEncoding;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\SynthesisInput;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\TextToSpeechClient;
use Google\Cloud\TextToSpeech\V1\VoiceSelectionParams;

// Authenticating with keyfile data.
/*echo "<br>";
print_r( $_ENV);
exit();*/

require_once 'config.php';

$text           = trim($_POST['text']);
$language_code  = trim($_POST['language']);
$voiceList      = TTS_APP_VOICES_LIST;
$selectLanguage = isset($voiceList[$language_code]) ? $voiceList[$language_code]:'';
$artisteName    = trim($_POST['artist_name']);
$gender         = trim($_POST['gender']);
if(empty($_POST['rate'])) {
$rate           = 1;
} else {
$rate           = $_POST['rate'];
}
if(empty($_POST['pitch'])) {
$pitch          = 1;
} else {
$pitch          = $_POST['pitch'];
}

$voice_quality  = $_POST['voice_quality'];
$u_id           = $_POST['u_id'];


// validate request
if (empty($text) || empty($selectLanguage) || empty($voice_quality) || empty($gender) || empty($artisteName) || empty($rate) || empty($pitch)){
    $response['success']    = false;
    $response['message']    = 'Required fields are empty';
    $response['data']       = [];
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
}

$textToSpeechClient = new TextToSpeechClient();
$input = new SynthesisInput();
$input->setText($text);
$voice = new VoiceSelectionParams();
$voice->setLanguageCode($language_code);

if (!empty($artisteName)){
    $voice->setName($artisteName);
}
if (!empty($gender)){
    $voice->setSsmlGender($gender == 'Female' ? 2:1);
}
$audioConfig = new AudioConfig();

if (!empty($rate)){
    $audioConfig->setSpeakingRate($rate);
}
if (!empty($pitch)){
    $audioConfig->setPitch($pitch);
}

$audioConfig->setAudioEncoding($voice_quality == 'WaveNet' ? AudioEncoding::OGG_OPUS:AudioEncoding::MP3);

$resp = $textToSpeechClient->synthesizeSpeech($input, $voice, $audioConfig);

// handle response file

$responseClass = new HandleResponseClass($resp);

$responseClass->saveFiles(TTS_APP_BASE_PATH);


/*=-=-= sending response -=-=-*/
$response = [
    'success'   => false,
    'message'   => 'something went wrong, please check your internet connection and try again later',
    'data'      => [],
];

if($responseClass->fileSaved()) {
    $response['success']    = true;
    $response['message']    = '';
    $response['data']       = [
        'down_link' => rtrim(TTS_APP_BASE_URL,'/').'/download.php?file='.urlencode($responseClass->getFileName()),
        'play_link' => rtrim(TTS_APP_BASE_URL,'/').'/'.$responseClass->getDirName().'/'.$responseClass->getFileName().'.mp3',
    ];
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
}

echo json_encode($response);
exit();
```

The error I m getting :

```
jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2          POST https://vdofy.com/tts-test/ajax.php 500
  send @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
  ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
  S.<computed> @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
  (anonymous) @ index?content_get= Test to speech tesing:1496
  dispatch @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
  v.handle @ jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2
```

Not sure why am I getting this error as I have not changed anything since it was working fine.
Please share your thoughts on what could have gone wrong.

Comment: is `https://vdofy.com/` your server - if not, then not much you can do, since the error is an **Internal Server Error**

Comment: It sound to me that they broke something on the other end of this API. I checked https://vdofy.com/home/ and it's not coming up... that's a bad sign. Oh, after about a minute it did show the front page.

Comment: @Bravo yes the vdofy.com is my server.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i know, it needs some speed issues, but the site is in my server.

Comment: then check your PHP server logs for the internal server error - the error is coming from inside the house ... I mean, server :p

Comment: If its your own internal server, Do you have access to it? could you do a small test and check if everything is fine on that side? ( a mock-up call? )

Comment: @Betjens yes, its my own server. i can do any test. can you tell me what kinda test..?

Comment: Shouldn't that be all the POST involve on ajax.php?

Comment: If it was me, I wouldn't use Google for that. Instead I'd use the [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API). It has less privacy concerns too.

Comment: Not many details about your server or file structure - but if you're editing off the server and posting changes to it by uploading files, I've had errors because of not setting the execute permission, or from uploading files with PC line ending - vs Unix EOL

Comment: At @Vdofy videos, were you able to retrieve the error message server side on tts_app.php. If it was working fine, it could be that your credential env value is not up to date or replaced.

Comment: Add error output then check the response in the Web Inspectors Network tab, `ini_set("display_errors", "On")` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)`,

Comment: Where did TTS_APP_BASE_URL come from?

Answer (score 1):

Response code 500 is a server side error, So check for errors in your server side PHP code, check error logs or turn on php error reporting to find what is causing the error.